# Run function after reducers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a function in java that is executed once after the reducer function completes. What I want to do is try to refine the output from the reducers so I need to run some code after the reducers completes the algorithm is there a possible way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ChainReducer`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainReducer.html) to add as many `Mappers` as you want after the `Reducer` in the same reducer task.

If you want to apply an other `Reducer`, you will need to start a new task with an identity mapper and the reducer task you want to execute.

As stated in the doc:

> Using the ChainMapper and the ChainReducer classes is possible to compose Map/Reduce jobs that look like [MAP+ / REDUCE MAP*]. And immediate benefit of this pattern is a dramatic reduction in disk IO.